# Sinatra, ActiveRecord, FactoryGirl, and has_many_through associations

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra, factory-bot, has-many-through

I am building a Sinatra API. My models use ActiveRecord and have a many-to-many model relationship.

```
class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  has_many :workouts_exercises, dependent: :destroy                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  has_many :exercises, through: :workouts_exercises                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  has_many :workouts_exercises                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  has_many :workouts, through: :workouts_exercises                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

class WorkoutsExercises < ActiveRecord::Base                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  belongs_to :workouts                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  belongs_to :exercises                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
end
```

I am trying to set up FactoryGirl to use these associations. Here is what I've got from reading all the docs I have found so far.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :workout do
    name 'Default Workout Factory Name'
    description 'Default Workout Factory Description'

    factory :workout_with_exercises do
      after(:create) do |workout|
        workout.exercises << FactoryGirl.create(:exercise)
      end
    end
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :exercise do
    name 'Default Exercise Factory Name'
    description 'Default Exercise Factory Description'
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :workouts_exercises do
    workout
    exercise
  end
end
```

Here is my test that I would like to run

```
it 'returns the associated exercises' do                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  workout = FactoryGirl.create(:workout_with_exercises)                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  associated_exercises = workout.exercises                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  expect(associated_exercises.count).to eq(1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
end
```

However, when I run the specs I receive

```
  1) Workout returns the associated exercises
 Failure/Error: workout.exercises << FactoryGirl.create(:exercise)

 NameError:
   uninitialized constant Workout::WorkoutsExercise
```

The first method of debugging I tried was to pry before workout= declaration. Workout doesn't know about the exercises attribute. According to the ActiveRecord documentation, setting up a many-to-many association should provide you with the 16 #collection methods. This would mean that #exercises should return all the associated Exercise objects for the Workout object.

I can't, for the life of me, figure out whether or not it's my AR associations in the models that are to blame - or the FactoryGirl configuration I have. I've checked the SQL tables and all of the columns seem to be appropriate. I could really use some help figuring out what the issue is.

I've tried a few other FactoryGirl after_create hooks, using the shovel operator and attempting to declare the workouts_exercises association explicitly:

```
 workout.exercises << [                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
     create(:exercise, name: 'Bench Press', workouts_exercises: workout),                                                                                                                                                                                                
     create(:exercise, name: 'Pushups', workouts_exercises: workout),                                                                                                                                                                                                    
     create(:exercise, name: 'DB Flys', workouts_exercises: workout)                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 ]
```

Again, failure.

My third attempt was to use the FactoryGirl callback methods from [ThoughtBot - ain't no calla back girl](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/aint-no-calla-back-girl).

```
factory :workout_with_exercises do
  after(:create) do |workout|
    FactoryGirl.create(:exercise, workout: workout)
  end
end
```

This results in

```
undefined method `exercise=' for #<Workout:0x007ff6250c2768>
```

Which makes me believe the AR associations aren't written correctly.

Thanks in advance for any help you can lend!

Answer (score 0):

I use Sinatra, ActiveRecord, and RSpec. Just recently, I added FactoryGirl to the mix.

In your test framework's initialization point (I use RSpec, which is spec_helper.rb), you'll need to require the file that contains your model classes.

Next, do your model classes live within a module?

My model classes don't exist at the top-level, because I instead put them in a module for better organization within the project.

With this pattern, I found that I needed to explicitly define the module + class path for FactoryGirl.

The following would **not** work:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :vendor do
    name 'Test Vendor
  end
end
```

But things began to work after I told FactoryGirl the full class name, like below:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :vendor, class: MyAppName::Models::Vendor do
    name 'Test Vendor
  end
end
```